# Windows OS level file open event trigger

Tags: windows, events, windows-server-2003, file-management

Colleagues, I have need to run a script/program on certain basic OS level events. In particular when a file in Windows is opened. The open may be read-only or to edit, and may be initiated by a number of means, either from windows explorer (open or ), be selected from a viewing or editing application from the native file chooser, or drag-n-drop into an editing or viewing application.

Further, i need the trigger to "hold" the event from completing the action until the runtime on the program has completed. The event handler program may return a pass state, or fail state. If fail state has been returned, then the event must disallow the initially requested action.

Lastly, I need to add to the file in question a property or attribute that will contain metadata that will be used by the above event trigger handler program to make a determination as to the pass/fail condition that will ultimately determine if the user is permitted to open the file.

Please note that this is NOT a windows event log situation, but one at the OS level file open event.

thanks very much for your help.

**Edit**

What I had hoped that someone was aware of was an OS level trigger, similar to how you can enable a trigger on an event-log writer occurance in Windows (ie: send an email, run a script when an event hits the event logger).

The application environment I work in, a PLM system, allows for event handling. So, when a user initiates an action, say a checkout of a file from an object, there are 3 available handlers or triggers that can be programmed. The "check" or "pre-action" trigger is a process that fires when the user starts initiates the event, but before the system permits it to be processed. So, one can block or otherwise alter the response of the system programmatically based on some condition, like user context.

I have also enabled startup/shutdown script firing via group policy, so i can delay a server shutdown until a database has closed properly. This was done in Windows server 2003. So, with that hook, i could manage shutdown or startup.

Hence, I had hoped someone might be aware of an OS trigger that would do the same for a file-open operation. This would be deployed on all workstations and desktops.

Again, if there are any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks again.

regards,
j

Comment: Sounds like you need a driver to intercept the calls at the FS level.

Comment: I wonder whether this is going to be an anti-virus or a DRM tool...

Comment: Are you aware there are thousands/sec IO operations when you right-click?

Answer (score 0):

A couple strategies come to mind.  One is to run the app with your own DLL to intercept API calls like WriteFile.  Another would be to run the app under the debugger interface.